# PHP eval(array_as_string) returns null

Tags: php, eval

```
$arr = eval("array('foo'=>'bar');");

// returns null
var_dump($arr);
```

Can someone please explain why did I get null instead of an array?

Comment: Why are you `eval`ing that string?  There has to be a better way to do this, such as `json_decode` or `unserialize`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to `return` the array.

From the [docs](http://php.net/eval):

> `eval()` returns `NULL` unless `return` is called in the evaluated code, in which case the value passed to `return` is returned.

So you need to do:

```
$arr = eval("return array('foo'=>'bar');");
```

Comment: got it, thanks. I didn't pay much attention to the `Return Value`, just looked at the example which doesn't use a `return`.

Comment: @user1643156: Why are you using `eval` in the first place?  It's slow and insecure.  There is probably a better way to do what you want.

Comment: @gen_Eric I don't know about user16... but I've got two variables and a selector in between. So `'return $rule["value"]' . $selector . '$target;'` will give me `true==true` but that can change depending on the variables. Is there a better way for this case?

Comment: I don't know if it's the best way, but I might do `switch($selector){}`, instead of using `eval()`.  Then something like `case '==': $ret = $rule['value'] == $target;`.

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean

```
eval("\$arr = array('foo'=>'bar');"); 

var_dump($arr);
```

Comment: You need to escape the `$`.  You are in double quotes, so PHP is trying to interpolate `$arr`, since it doesn't exist you wind up `eval`ing `" = array('foo'=>'bar');"`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `eval` is highly discouraged as explained in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php).

Also, you should be doing something like `$arr = eval("return array('foo'=>'bar');");` ie. initialising `$arr` with the eval function. See it in action [here](http://codepad.org/liRuHaai)

Comment: thanks, I'm aware of the evil part of eval(). the function is only used by me (admin).

Answer (score 0):

The eval function executes the php code given to it. 
As your code returns nothing, it gives null.
You need to return the array and store it  in a variable like,

```
$arr = eval("return array('foo'=>'bar');");
```